# Workflow column not showing on list nor in 'modify this view'

Tags: list, workflow

I can't figure out how to fix this, the workflow status column is not showing up on the list, I tried to set it on 'modify this view' but the workflow column is not showing up.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you published your workflow successfully? Try adding Set workflow status action in your workflow and republish it.

Comment: Yes, it was working perfectly. It's working fine on production but doesn't show on UAT. I haven't changed anything since last year, that's really odd.

Answer (score 0):

Publish workflow and run first instance, the status column will automatically appear in View and in View properties